# Dynamic partitioning

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, partitioning, data-partitioning

I have created an external table in hive using:

```
create external table if not exists summary(
    `Restaurant ID` INT,
    `Restaurant Name` STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (p_filedate INT, p_country_name STRING)
stored as ORC;
```

Now, when I try to populate the table using:

```
INSERT overwrite table zomato_summary partition(p_filedate,p_country_name)
SELECT  
        `restaurant id`,
         ISNULL( `restaurant name`,'NA')
FROM Sales;
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function any
```

Probably Hive is viewing the **partition** keyword as an UDF, that's why it is causing error.

Please suggest alternative method of dynamic partitioning on multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

When loading partitions in dynamic mode, select should include partition columns (in the same order as in table DDL).

For example like this:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT overwrite table zomato_summary partition(p_filedate,p_country_name)
SELECT  
        `restaurant id`,
         ISNULL( `restaurant name`,'NA'), --ISNULL exists not in all versions, use COALESCE or NVL
         current_date, --or proper column from sales 
         country_name
FROM Sales;
```